# Is there a way to see if there will be wifi on a given German Intercity train connection?

Tags: trains, germany, internet, wifi

On Deutsche Bahn's [site about their train fleet](https://int.bahn.de/en/trains/wifi), it's noted that wifi is available on all ICE trains and "some" Intercity trains. For ICE connections, I can therefore assume there’ll be something resembling wifi. But is there a way to know whether a given *Intercity* connection will (usually) be served by a train with wifi or not in advance, so one could for example have an idea of whether one could get some remote work done on a lengthy train ride? I'm assuming that the actual trains are marked with wifi symbols when wifi is available, but by the point one can see that it's a little late for advance planning.

Comment: I highly doubt it. There is quite a bit of last minute train swapping happening these days. You can count yourself lucky if the advertised number of cars and your reserved seat actually show up.

Comment: @Hilmar true, knowing DB I'm probably being overly optimistic just asking "is there a way to know whether a given Intercity connection will be served by a train"...

Comment: As far as I know all ice trains have wifi. I never been in one without (that is, they have routers and wifi network). However, it doesn't work all the time, often in places without 4g/3g cover. And sometimes it's quite slow for the whole trip.

Comment: From my experience on ICE trains, I'm usually better off creating a mobile hotspot from my (5G-capable) phone with a Telekom contract compared to using the wifi.

Comment: For the ICE trains I know (and eh, slow wifi is better than EU data prices), it’s the Intercity (IC) ones that I‘m not so sure on.

Answer (score 1):

I found the [reiseauskunft page of DB](https://reiseauskunft.bahn.de/bin/bhftafel.exe/en) which allows you to search all departing trains from a certain station, using filters on date, time and type of train.

If you click on the resulting train and scroll down, there is a free text section that describes what amenities are available:

[image]

Perhaps that is a source you can use?

Comment: That’s a good overview! Though I’m currently on a train with wifi for which no such thing is noted on that page… shame, it’s informative otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for checking real life against the website! I am tempted to remove this answer now as it explicitly does not answer your question, so please bookmark the DB page if you found it useful :)

Answer (score 1):

The desired information is associated with *individual cars*, not the trainset as a whole.
Obviously wifi has a limited range.

1. Go to German Rail timetable information.
2. Click on *Show details*.
3. Either

   1. Click on *Coach sequence* toward the bottom of the now visible section.
      You can now select any stop and a coach sequence is shown.
   2. There is a key.
      A Wi‑Fi symbol [image: WLAN] indicates cars with Wi-Fi if available.

   or

   1. Click on a train name e. g. *IC 1234*.
      A new window opens.
   2. Click on *Coach Sequence* in the top right area.
      A new window opens.
      From here on it is the same as above.

Notes:

- The *coach sequence* button is not always available so you cannot use it for long-term planning.
  You will need to resort to third-party sites such as Bahn.expert which may provide information regardless yet have different interfaces.
- Apparently Wi-Fi information is *omitted* if trains are pretty much always equipped with Wi‑Fi, e. g. the ICE fleet.

Comment: Good point - I’m used to it being an all or nothing setup rather than differing for individual cars (plus messaging here is „everyone on the train [as opposed to the individual car] shares the same connection (so don’t download huge files)“). Will say I’ve just poked around on Bahn.expert without spotting any IC trains with cars with wifi - unfortunately I’m in the wrong country to nip down to the station and verify like I could for Reiseauskunft where I happened to be on the actual train. That said, Bahn.expert looks incredibly useful anyway!